# Will I get an error message if I ordered a domain name which turns to not be available?

Tags: google-domains

When [reading the terms of service](https://domains.google.com/tos), I saw :

> Google does not guarantee that Registrant will be able to register or renew a desired domain name, even if Google’s systems indicate that the domain name is available or **Registrant is able to complete an order** with respect to such domain name.

and

> Registrar shall give no guarantee for a successful allocation of ordered domains and becomes free from the duty to perform the service in case of impossibility of the order.

Will I get an error messages in the webapp if I order a domain which isn't available, or will it silently fail *(by silently fail I mean the website still claims I own the domain because the order was successful)* ?
I can't test it since no bank allow to open accounts in foreign currencies for individuals in my country *(the foreign currency being $)*

If it silently fails, then it would confirm a server security vulnerability *(I would be able to take ownership of the google.com domain in Webmaster Tools)*.

Comment: I think this would be better asked at [webmasters.se] because you'll reach more people who use Google Domains there.

Comment: I am going to reopen this because it's *technically* about using the web interface of this Google site.  Regardless of whether it was closed on Webmasters, it probably does belong there because at its core, it's about creating a domain for a website, which is a stage in the "development" of such a presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there’s a message telling the payment had failed. I tested this recently.

Answer (score 0):

Google is basically trying to remove themselves from being responsible if you do not get the domain name you order.  They are basically saying that if you go to check to see if a domain is available, and it is... and then you order it a few seconds later it is taken, Google is stating that they aren't responsible for it not being available.  Google basically has no control over all of the domains.  There are many companies that can order/register domains and thus this being the structure of how domains are registered, it is impossible to guarantee you will get yours even if you looked it up seconds ago.  Would you get an error if you tried to order it and it wasn't available?  Yes.  Once you order it you need to also fill in information that tells the DNS servers how to find your website.  You also need to fill out your information and other things.  Check out whois.net and play with that a bit.  You'll see what other information you need to fill out once you do register a domain name.